# Jetty 9.3.9.v20160517 Provider WebSocketCdiInitializer not found when enabling Annotations

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

When deploying a webapp using the `DeploymentManager`, this error is thrown

```
2016-06-06 15:19:37,750 WARN  [org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager] (WrapperSimpleAppMain) Unable to reach node goal: started (DeploymentManager.java:506)
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.cdi.websocket.WebSocketCdiInitializer not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.getNonExcludedInitializers(AnnotationConfiguration.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1361)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
```

This happens when enabling annotations support using:

```
    org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
    classlist.addBefore(
        "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration"
    );
    classlist.addAfter(
        "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration"
    );
```

The jar `cdi-websocket-9.3.9.v20160517.jar` is in the class path

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547542/why-netbeans-jetty-plugin-doesnt-run-but-jettyrun-works-on-my-project) suggests to deactivate the `cdi` Jetty module, but it does not say how to do it with an embedded Jetty.

How do I fix this ?

**EDIT**

We realize that this issue may be caused by the (complex) environment the application is running in.

Therefore, I am particularly interested in understanding **what** are the root reasons that could cause this exception to be thrown

**CONCLUSION**

TD;LR: Jetty-9.3.9 embedded != Jetty-9.3.9 standalone

With Jetty 9.2.14 we were starting jetty programmatically (just like a Jetty embedded) but using the jars of the unpackaged version of a standalone Jetty.

We have had this set-up working fine since Jetty 7 (or maybe even 6) but things started to break when upgrading to Jetty 9.3.9.

Note: we are using Jersey, servlets and a very few JSPs. No websockets. We are upgrading to test HTTP/2.

Comment: Actually, the better way to say it is that `jetty-cdi-*` is specifically designed for the standalone `jetty-distribution` and its module system.  which is overly complicated (and pointless) to use when you are in `embedded-jetty`.  The easier solution is to just use `cdi-weld` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you are jetty-embedded, the solution is simple.

Do not include the `jetty-cdi-*` jars in your project.
They are not meant to be used from embedded jetty.

Use the `cdi-weld` artifacts directly from the weld project for Jetty Embedded.

Be sure you read the weld documentation on how to setup the `WebAppClassloader` to allow weld to see the server components. (this is called "punching a hole in the webapp isolation layer")

Comment: Thanks. I am not forgetting you: we are running tests and will give you feedback

Comment: I will edit my question with our findings. Both answers actually provided hints on what to do; yours more than the other one, so I am awarding it to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From source code of Jetty 9.3.2 [[1]](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-annotations/9.3.2.v20150730/org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationConfiguration.java?av=f) *(I suppose the lines have not changed after coming to 9.3.9)* I found the following source code snippet:

```
851         //Get initial set of SCIs that aren't from excluded jars or excluded by the containerExclusionPattern, or excluded
852         //because containerInitializerOrdering omits it
853         for (ServletContainerInitializer sci:loadedInitializers)
854         {       
855             if (matchesExclusionPattern(sci)) 
856             {
857                 if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("{} excluded by pattern", sci);
858                 continue;
859             }
860             
861             Resource sciResource = getJarFor(sci);
862             if (isFromExcludedJar(context, sci, sciResource)) 
863             { 
864                 if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("{} is from excluded jar", sci);
865                 continue;
866             }
```

There the comment tells that SCI (ServletContainerInitializer) is here checked for being not excluded by any reasons. Your stacktrace told us line 864 is throwing an exception. LOG.debug tries to tell that the reason is that the SCI **is from excluded jar** thus causing the error you faced.

My suggestion is you check your maven configurations (your pom.xml) about the package containg **org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration** file in:

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-annotations -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>9.3.9.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

[[2]](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-annotations/9.3.9.M1) and that this dependency is not excluded from some wierd reason. I suppose the jar refers to the maven dependency.

**My sources:**

[1]
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-annotations/9.3.2.v20150730/org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationConfiguration.java?av=f

[2] 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-annotations/9.3.9.M1

Comment: Thanks. I am not forgetting you: we are running tests and will give you feedback

Comment: I will edit my question with our findings. Both answers actually provided hints on what to do; @Joakim Erdfelt more than yours, so I am awarding it to him. Thanks for your time